# How to deal with void* conversion when dealing with INT_MIN and LONG_MIN?

Tags: c, hex

I'm trying to write a function that will be able to print a `void*` using the `write` function. You can see my code bellow, works for some scenarios, but it fails when I try to use values such as `INT_MIN`, `LONG_MIN`, or even `INT_MAX`.

This function is part of my own implementation of a printf function. I'm using the write function and while loops because `for loop` and `fputc` are not allowed.

```
static int write_hex(unsigned char *buffer, int i)
{
    char    tmp;
    int     leading_zero;
    int     counter;

    leading_zero = 1;
    counter = 0;
    tmp = "0123456789abcdef"[buffer[i] / 16];
    if (tmp != '0' || !leading_zero)
    {
        write(1, &tmp, 1);
        leading_zero = 0;
        counter++;
    }
    tmp = "0123456789abcdef"[buffer[i] % 16];
    if (tmp != '0' || !leading_zero)
    {
        write(1, &tmp, 1);
        leading_zero = 0;
        counter++;
    }
    return (counter);
}

int handle_pointer(va_list args)
{
    int             i;
    int             counter;
    void            *ptr;
    unsigned char   *buffer;
    
    ptr = va_arg(args, void*);
    buffer = malloc(sizeof(ptr));
    ft_memcpy(buffer, &ptr, sizeof(ptr));
    i = 0;
    write(1, "0x", 2);
    counter = 2;
    while (buffer[i])
    {
        counter += write_hex(buffer, i);
        i++;
    }
    free(buffer);
    return (counter);
}
```

Result of failing test (printf is what is expected, ft_printf is the output):

```
args:      [" %p %p ", INT_MIN, INT_MAX]
printf:    [ 0x80000000 0x7fffffff ] = 23
ft_printf: [ 0x 0xffffff7f ] = 15
```

Comment: What would a successful test look like? Also, why not use the standard `fputc` instead of `write` to write a character?

Comment: `INT_MIN` and `INT_MAX` aren't pointers. You shouldn't try to print them with `%p` format.

Comment: Make sure you understand the problem you're solving. It's more than what you suspect. `while (buffer[i])` is also terrible since pointers can have zeroes in them and there's nothing to stop that loop from going *way* past the bounds of `buffer`. https://godbolt.org/z/oT1b8b5co

Comment: @TedLyngmo I'm using write because it is a requirement of the task I need to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You're on an little-endian machine, so 0x7FFFFFFF is stored as 0xFF,FF,FF,7F. That explains `0xffffff7f`.
- `while (buffer[i])` makes no sense because it causes you to stop printing when you encounter a 0x00 byte, such as the first byte of 0x80000000. That explains `0x`. It also means you could read far more than intended and resulting in undefined behaviour.

```c
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define STDOUT 1

static const char *hex_syms = "0123456789abcdef";

static void write_hex_reversed( size_t n, void *buffer ) {
   unsigned char *p = (unsigned char *)buffer + n;
   for ( size_t i = n; i--; ) {
      --p;
      write( STDOUT, hex_syms + ( *p / 16 ), 1 );
      write( STDOUT, hex_syms + ( *p % 16 ), 1 );
   }
}

static void handle_pointer( va_list argp ) {
   void *p = va_arg( argp, void* );
   write( STDOUT, "0x", 2 );
   write_hex_reversed( sizeof( p ), &p );  // This is a LE machine.
}

// `n` takes place of the format string in this simpler code.
static void my_formatted_write( size_t n, ... ) {
   va_list argp;
   va_start( argp, n );
   for ( size_t i = n; i--; ) {
      handle_pointer( argp );
      if ( i ) write( STDOUT, " ", 1 );
   }

   va_end( argp );
}

int main( void ) {
   void *int_min_as_ptr = (void*)(uintptr_t)(unsigned)INT_MIN;  // Why???
   void *int_max_as_ptr = (void*)(uintptr_t)(unsigned)INT_MAX;  // Why???
   my_formatted_write( 2, int_min_as_ptr, int_max_as_ptr );
   write( STDOUT, "\n", 1 );
}
```

Output:

```
0x0000000080000000 0x000000007fffffff
```

Known bugs:

- `write` isn't guaranteed to write as many bytes as requested. It needs to be called in a loop when the third argument isn't 1. Probably better to build up a buffer than doing all these writes, though.
- No checking/reporting of `write`'s success.
- I don't know if `va_list argp` as the argument is guaranteed to work since you expect the variable in the caller to change. An indirect should probably be used (`*argpp` instead of `argp`).